# Finding the closest special node in a weighted graph

Tags: data-structures, dijkstra, undirected-graph

If we are given a weighted undirected graph in which some nodes are marked as special nodes then how to find for each node v the special node with least cost to reach using Dijkstra?

This [solution](https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/9751280)  to a problem uses this concept but i can't figure out how it works. Can someone provide a proof or explanation of it?

Comment: Do you want the closest special node, or the special node that requires the least cost to reach?

Comment: I want to find for each node v its boss[v] i.e the special node that requires the least cost to reach.